# Do ColdFusion scheduled tasks have a default timeout?

Tags: coldfusion

Do scheduled tasks follow the application settings for timeouts?
Can you override with `<cfsetting requesttimeout= "x">`?
Which request timeout takes priority CFIDE/Administrator or cfsetting?

Comment: You may want to check this blog posting. It may help. Brian discusses a way to synch cfschedule and cfhttp. http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/07/22/get-current-requesttimeout

Answer (score 4):

Yes they follow the application timeout.

`<CFSETTING>` override the CFIDE timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a timeout specifically for the scheduled task in its setup with the "Timeout (sec)" field.

Comment: If the scheduler calls a CF template with `<cfsetting>` which timeout setting wins?

Comment: just checked. cfschedule timeout overrides request timeout in cfide. cfsetting overrides cfschedule

Comment: How is that possible.  The timeout of CFSCHEDULE determines how long the CFHTTP call will wait before it declares the page request timed out.  If global request-timeout or cfsetting or url.RequestTimeout is set to a lower value, then the cfsetting/request-timeout/url.RequestTimeout will trigger and return a 500 error to CHSCHEDULE and CFSCHEDULE will return.

Comment: Even if the cfhttp call is made, the task will continue to run for the time specified in the <cfsetting> on the page. So, the scheduled task will not timeout based on the CFSCHEDULE timeout value but based on the <cfsetting> value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two timeouts you need to worry about with CFSCHEDULE.

- The timeout used by the CFHTTP tag
  which is the one you provide when you
  create a new task.
- The timeout you provide as the default in Server Settings: Timeout Requests after ( seconds).

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old post, it is still an open question. After a few tests, we found out that scheduled tasks have a **default timeout of approximately 5 minutes**.

After setting the timeout inside the task manager our process, which takes about 7 Minutes ran through with no problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is an old post. Basically, the question sucks because I didn't condense the idea down into a single question. 

I never found the answer I was looking for. Essentially, I need to reword the post, do the research and post the answer.

If you invoke it from inside the ColdFusion Administrator, then there's a 5 minute hardcap. You can see that it's hardcoded within the encrypted source.